# Remove Context-Menu close delay

Tags: antd

I want to use a [antd context-menu](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/) on a d3js-svg, which works totally fine. However, this context-menu has a "closing" delay, that doesn't feel right for this application.

[image]

Is there a proper way to remove this closing delay? (I tried different values for `transitionName` and `mouseLeaveDelay` without any success)

```js
<Dropdown overlay={this.state.contextMenu.menu} trigger={['contextMenu']}>
    <svg height='70vh' width='100%'>
    </svg>
</Dropdown>
```

Thanks in advance!

old (with `mouseLeaveDelay={0}`):

```js
<Dropdown mouseLeaveDelay={0} overlay={this.state.contextMenu.menu} trigger={['contextMenu']}>
    <svg height='70vh' width='100%'>
    </svg>
</Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `mouseLeaveDelay={0}`it looks like it is an optional parameter and could be the culprit.

Since soemthing like this works:

```
  <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
    <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
      Hover me <Icon type="down" />
    </a>
  </Dropdown>,
```

I would guess it has something to do with how you created menu or your context menu trigger. Perhaps it is hung up at `contextMenu`. Try making it as simple as possible following the example and then work your way back to your solution and you will find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question (removed `mouseLeaveDelay` and recorded the new behavior)

Comment: Thanks for investigating. Hm.. I get the same behavior with your example. This slight delay of closing, when moving the mouse out of the region. (gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEOqX.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css

```
.ant-dropdown {
    animation-duration: 0s !important;
}
```

Hope, this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really hoped, to solve it with a CSS-property like you proposed, but unfortunately it didn't work. (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8pOh.gif)